# Can I create a category section at the bottom of my Wiki pages like in Wikipedia?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, enterprise-wiki, categories

At the bottom of every Wikipedia page is a 'Bring Together' block that links to everything the current page is connected to. For instance, when viewing the page for [Thor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thor) you will find this at the bottom:

[image]

It breaks down all of the connections and such that this page has and it's hierarchy.

I don't need something even HALF as complex and powerful as this. I would simply like to list out links to all related Wiki Pages where the Wiki Categories were the same.

Is this an option and, if so, how would I go about creating this?

Answer (score 1):

I can propose an alternative that can do something similar. Create an enterprise wiki site. All pages on the enterprise wiki site comes with a "Categories" column for you to tag the post. Your audience can then click on these "Categories" and it will bring them to a page with a list of pages with the same "Category" tagged.

[image]

Comment: How do I present these categories on each page? Can that presentation be done automatically?

Comment: @randomblink I have edited my posted with a screenshot to what I am referring to. The "Categories" section is on the right and applies for all the pages that are created under the Enterprise Wiki Site